# Find the closed form of the recurrence equation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

$f_{n}=0.5f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}+1$

Hey, I'm trying to find the closed form of this recurrence equation. I tried the plug and chug method but couldn't get it, can someone kindly explain this to me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I tried the plug and chug method" Could you be anymore specific? Do not hesitate to expand the details of what you did.

Comment: Look to the characteristic polynomial of the homogeneous recurrence, which in this case is $x^2-0.5x-2$.  By quadratic formula, this has roots $\frac{0.5\pm\sqrt{8.25}}{2}$.  Calling those roots $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and since the nonhomogeneous part is a constant and $1$ is not one of the roots of the characteristic polynomial, this implies the closed form is of the form $f_n = c_1\lambda_1^n+c_2\lambda_2^n+d$ for some constants $c_1,c_2$ and $d$, where $d$ can be solved for normally and $c_1$ and $c_2$ depend on initial conditions if any exist.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

I suppose that what is making the problem is the $+1$ in $$f_n=\frac 12 f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}+1$$ To get rid of it, let $f_n=g_n+a$ and replace 
$$g_n+a=\frac 12 (g_{n-1}+a)+2(g_{n-2}+a)+1$$ that is to say$$g_n=\frac 12 g_{n-1}+2g_{n-2}+(\frac 32 a+1)$$ To go back to the standard problem, may be, you could set $a=??$